# Too high fit value in chi distribution histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics, data-science

I need to fit a histogram with a chi distribution. I am using scipy python library.
In some cases of data, the fit works very well, but in other cases, the first value of the pdf get from chi fitted is ridiculously high.

I don't understand this behaviour, I will try to show you images.

That is a good fit. The picture shows a histogram plot with matplotlib hist() and a histogram plot with matplotlib bar() function with the chi fit.

[image]

And in the follow picture I show a bad fit:

[image]

The code to plot the pdf with chi distribution is:

```
    lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(data))
    x, y, z = stats.chi.fit(data)
    pdf_chi = stats.chi.pdf(lnspc, x, y, z)
```

And the result in bad cases is a pdf_chi with too high values.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you have an offset? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution

Comment: Did you normalize the PDF to sum to 1? `pdf /= pdf.sum()`

Comment: No... but that does the pdf curve too low. It seems to change the scale (k) of the distribution to fix the problem in some cases. At moment I will iterate until finding the best scale value.

Comment: the PDF obtained with `scipy.stats` needs anyhow to be normalized because, being a Probability Density Function, the area under the curve needs to sum to 1 (100% of probability, see CDF) and `sps.anything.pdf` does not return an already normalized PDF. `sps.chi.fit` returns: degrees of freedom `df`, mean `loc` and `scale` (you denoted as `x`, `y`, `z`) can you post this results for bad fits?

Comment: May I ask why do you want to fit your data on a chi distribution? That's strictly related to chi-square distribution, so to sum of squares and Euclidean distances. Thus, it's a very specific distribution. Did you try to fit your data to a more "general" distribution, for example gamma?

Comment: The bad results do not fit with histogram with normalized PDF because PDF is very low. In theory, the histogram is normalized with density=True with numpy. I want chi because we are working with sigmas and not with variances, but maybe we can use chi-square too.

Comment: It seems I solved the problem adjust the scale factor (k) of the fit

Comment: @jatorna could you post how exactly you solve this?